# Migrate bak-file to older version of SQL server using command line

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy a bak file from sql server 2019 and restore it to a sql server 13.0.5026.0.
The conversion from one version to another that I have seen this far is using a [wizard](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/).

However, I need to do this non-interactively, so I need a command line utility.

How?

Answer (score 2):

I think the way forward is via a dacpac & fortunately for you the dbatools powershell library automates most of the process - check out the [blog post](https://dbatools.io/clone/).

Answer (score 1):

No, is not possible to downgrade a database.

You have to automate the export/import of the data as you saw on that article through PowerShell or Python but there are no tools that allow you to do that. Not in bulk, not from a GUI or command line.

So write your own command line utility because we live in an imperfect World.